# Ricoh Aficio MP171SPF: Scan to Folder not working

Tags: networking, windows-8, network-shares, smb, scanning

The scanning functionality on my MP171 is not working over my network.

All the necessary configurations have been made using the web interface, but it cannot authenticate. It throws several different errors (when I change settings):

> Sending failed. Please check settings and Check Scan Status
>
> Dest. authentication failed...

When I select "Dest." from the scanning screen, select SMB, and browse the network, the computer is listed. However, when I select the computer (in WORKGROUP), it just says, "Entered path is not correct..

I am sharing a folder on the network for scanning, and all permissions are enabled.

Using Windows 8 x64, but the problem also persists on Windows 7 x86 and x64.

Any pointers?

#### Update:

The most prominent error is this:

> Entered path was not correct.

However, the machine can see the PC (under Scan > Dest. > Browse Network). If I try manually, and leave the password off, it asks for authentication. To me, this means that it is successfully authenticating.

I phoned client support at Nashua (distributors of the machine), who said Windows 8 is not supported. However, as mentioned, it doesn't work on Windows 7 either.

Per the comment below, all other workstations on the network are able to access the folder.

Comment: Are you using a password to log in? Please try accessing the share from another PC, preferably with Linux, to rule out any and all implicit authentication methods.

Comment: I am using a password to log in - have also tried without password protection on both the machine, and the client PC. The folder is available to all other workstations on the network (there are three, one of which runs Ubuntu). I'm updating my question with the most prominent error that appears now.

Comment: By the way, I have managed to get the main PC to scan via WIA (which the manufacturer claimed was not possible). But that's not ideal in the long term.

Comment: And then that stopped working. TWAIN worked, but the quality was rubbish. Managed to get it working with Windows 7.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/scan-to-folder-through-smb-scan-is-notworking-in/c46bad27-b9f2-4abe-b920-a33a362af0b5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can totally feel your frustration. I've spent several hours trying to get a similar Ricoh machine to scan to network folder. We even got the local Ricoh dealer to send their technician out and he couldn't figure it out. I really believe that Ricoh's firmware needs to be updated to work properly with the newer versions of Windows or something.

I did find one workaround that may or may not be an option for you. I installed Filezilla Server on our main computer and configured it to run as a service. I setup a ftp username/password with the home directory set to the scans folder. I then configured the Aficio to scan via ftp rather than smb. It works beautifully now. The folks using the scanner don't even know we are using ftp rather than smb.

Side note. We are still waiting on the Tech to get back to us on why SMB isn't working properly.

Comment: Hi Kirb, and thanks for the response. Wes mentioned the firmware update too - I will be checking that out. The FTP idea sounds good - I certainly didn't even think of that. If I have issues with the firmware updates (say, none are available - the machine was just refurbished), then I will do it via FTP, which is pretty efficient, the way I see it.

Comment: I have just tried the FTP method, but the printer cannot connect. Means I'm doing something wrong. I have set it up with the defaults - port 21, etc. Created a user (no group) with a password. Created a shared folder in the FZS Interface, gave it an alias, but it still won't see it. My phone can see it, however. Will still need to check on another PC when it becomes available.

Comment: Have just got it working - was the firewall. So I allowed the inbound connection for the private profile, and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues you're likely running into here.

First, it's possible that the copier only supports the original SMB spec. I see this a lot with networked copy machines. In Windows Vista onwards, Microsoft deprecated SMB in favor of SMB2. Windows 8 upped that to SMB3.  The only way to get SMB2/3 support would be to do a firmware update on the copier, and this is usually something that can only be done by an authorized Ricoh technician (most of these companies do not publish their firmware updates to the general public).

Second, the computer hosting the share must not have a local account with a blank password.  The default security in Windows is to disable remote connectivity to shares using accounts with blank passwords.

You can attempt to mitigate the SMB issues by disabling SMB2/3 support on the computer hosting the share.  You will need PowerShell installed in order to do this.  On the host computer, type the following commands into an elevated PowerShell prompt:

For a Windows 8/Server 2012 host:

```
Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB2Protocol $false
Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB1Protocol $true
```

For a Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 host:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB2 -Type DWORD -Value 0 -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB1 -Type DWORD -Value 1 -Force
```

Note that disabling SMB2 also disables SMB3 (the two are dependent upon one another).  That's why there is no disable SMB3 command.  Also note that you must reboot the computer for these changes to take effect.

Give that a try and let us know how it worked out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, Wes. I have been given access to update the firmware on the machine - so I will check to see if there are any updates. I did create a specific user account for the scanning - it has a password, so that won't be an issue. Will send feedback once I've done any necessary upgrades.

Comment: Hi Wes - I did give it a try this morning, still does not work. Restarted the host PC, and the printer and network just to be sure. Still says that the entered path was not correct, even though it is. Will give the FTP thing a try - sounds viable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution specific to my environment.

After long long long hours of search, of comparing network cards, protocols versions, softwares and services installed on my  2008 servers I realised a similar thing: each of my server I couldn't reach by scan to folder had 2 services installed:

Sentinel protection server and Sentinel key server

Theses services where installed with the Avaya suite of our IP office. Once these services were deactivated the scan to folder where back and ok on these 2008 R2 servers.

I hope this will help others with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I do support work for a medium size company and I have had this issue with any Windows 7 machine primarily that have upgraded to Windows 10. What has resolved my issue with 90% of these cases is turning off the Password Protected Sharing in the Advanced Sharing Options in Network And Sharing. However, if a PC is running a 3rd party firewall or if user decided decides to change the USER name of the pc, you're going to run into a big issue that I have yet to find a solution for.

Comment: So you address OP's problem by stating that some cases can cause problems you don't know how to fix?  This is not an answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing this the same way.  The new "problems" are avoidable/uncommon situations, so documenting them is helpful.  Technically, the only question actually asked was "Any pointers?"  This seems a fair attempt at providing helpful info, and even a possible solution that could help some people.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default smb port number 139 to 445,using the telnet editing.
Go to cmd,
Edit telnet ip address of the machine,
Enter machine login name and password,
Enter smb client port445 enter smb client auth.1,
Enter log off enter,
Type yes to save settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Scan to Folder (SMB) in Windows 7+ with Ricoh MP C2050. Looks like SMB protocol is not supported and I wasn't prepared to find a fix again.

In the end I went for the Scan to FTP option but instead of installing Filezilla Server like the accepted answer says I setup a FTP site in IIS, shared the FTP folder across the network, then scanned to that folder using the FTP user I created.

Comment: I know this post is already quite ancient but could you elaborate a little on the FTP user bit? I wasn't asked to specify a user/pw in IIS but the printer requires it. Windows user/pw doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: @Robert you can setup individual FTP sites in IIS by using local server accounts. As long as the folder name is the same as the local user name IIS maps the two together. There are a few guides knocking around telling you how.

Comment: thanks, I figured the first part with the FTP sites, but the setup of the sites itself is unclear. haven't found any guide either. Will keep digging.

Comment: it all falls under the same FTP site in IIS but each 'local user' under the FTP site is the area for the separate sites. there are guides out there but I remember I did have to do some digging.

Answer (score -2):

I found that you often need to enter user and password for folder on the printer itself rather than through web interface. Might help someone :)

Comment: Can you edit the answer to elaborate on how to accomplish that?  Thanks.  [From review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/592001)